# Weighted Randoms

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I've have a database of items which has a field called 'weight'. I have a script which picks an determined number amount of items (set by me) from the database and order by rand()/weight. I determine the weight based on it's value/worth something like

```
 if($value <= 100000) {
 $weight = mt_rand(90, 110);
  $update_array = array(
  "weight" => $weight
    );
  } elseif($value >= 201000 && $value <= 250000) {
     $weight = mt_rand(60, 89);
      $update_array = array(
      "weight" => $weight
    );
  }
```

and so on... Is there a better way of calculating the weights and doing a weighted random sql query? Thanks.

Comment: Could just use the $value as your weight. Then choose to make a smaller number a heavier weight.